# Relative import of package __init__.py

Tags: python, package, python-module

Suppose I have a package containing two submodules and also a substantial amount of code in `__init__.py` itself:

```
pkg/__init__.py
pkg/foo.py
pkg/bar.py
```

and, to make planned future refactorings easier, I want components of the package to exclusively use relative imports to refer to each other.  In particular, `import pkg` should never appear.

From `foo.py` I can do

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import bar
```

to get access to the `bar.py` module, and vice versa.

The question is, *what do I write to import `__init__.py` in this manner?*  I want exactly the same effect as `import pkg as local_name`, only without having to specify the absolute name `pkg`.

```
#import pkg as local_name
from . import ??? as local_name
```

---

**UPDATE:** Inspired by maxymoo's answer, I tried

```
from . import __init__ as local_name
```

This does not set `local_name` to the the module defined by `__init__.py`; it instead gets what appears to be a bound method wrapper for the `__init__` *method* of that module.  I suppose I could do

```
from . import __init__ as local_name
local_name = local_name.__self__
```

to get the thing I want, but (a) yuck, and (b) this makes me worry that the module hasn't been fully initialized.

Answers need to work on *both* Python 2.7 and Python 3.4+.

Yes, it would probably be better to hollow out `__init__.py` and just have it reexport stuff from the submodules, but that can't happen just yet.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing special about the dunders (they're just discouraged when writing your own module/function names); you should just be able to do

```
from .__init__ import my_function as local_name
```

Comment: I don't want to import specific functions from `__init__.py`, I want the *entire module*.

Comment: Explicitly importing the `__init__` module reexecutes the module, resulting in tow _different_ modules (`pkg is pkg.__init__` is False). Each has its own namespace. If you change something in `pkg` (say somthing like `pkg.config.setSomeValue(...)`) it won't affect the counterpart in `pkg.__init__`.

Comment: @mata This is starting to feel like a bug report :-/

Comment: @zwol could you do `from .__init__ import *`?

Comment: @maxymoo No, that would dump a huge amount of junk into the submodule and it would also require extensive and painful code changes.

Answer (score 1):

- python2 and python3 (uses the [discouraged](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) `__import__`):

  - from 1st level module (`pkg.foo`, `pgk.bar`, ...):

    ```
    local_name = __import__("", globals(), locals(), [], 1)
    ```
  - from module in subpackage (`pkg.subpkg.foo`, ...):

    ```
    local_name = __import__("", globals(), locals(), [], 2)
    ```
- python3 only*:

  - From `pkg.foo` or `pkg.bar`:

    ```
    import importlib
    local_name = importlib.import_module("..", __name__)
    ```
  - From `pkg.subpkg.baz`:

    ```
    import importlib
    local_name = importlib.import_module("...", __name__)
    ```

*`import_module` on python2 tries load `pkg.` in this case, unfortunately.